# Can I delete a migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, rake

When I ran `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare` I got the following:

```
rake aborted!
Multiple migrations have the name CreateMicroposts
```

To check the status of my migration files, I ran

```
rake db:migrate:status
```

And got:

Status      Migration ID         Migration Name
-------   ---------------     -----------------

up     20120616205407          Create users

up     20120622103932          Add index to users email

up     20120622114559         Add password digest to users

up     20120628095820         Add remember token to users

up     20120704123654         Add admin to users

down    20120706103254          Create microposts

up     20120707073410           Create microposts

As you can see, I have two migration files with the exact same names and the exact same code in them. It's only their statuses differ, i.e. Up and Down.

What does Up and Down signify?

And which one can I delete, if I have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two different migration files containing the header

```
class CreateMicroposts< ActiveRecord::Migration
```

rake db:migrate:status does not check the status of your migration files. It tells you what migrations will be applied if you run rake db:migrate. The up/down labels are pretty much self-explanatory: it tells you whether the migration will be applied via the up method or the down method. The up method is ran when you migrate and the down when you rollback a migration. You can make some further reading about Rails migrations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Answer (score 0):

`up` is the method called when "evolving" (ie migrating to a new schema), while `down` is the method called when "regressing" (ie migrating to an older schema version, because one of your changes doesn't suit you). `db:migrate` calls `up`, `db:rollback` calls `down`. In recent versions of rails, there's `change` that handles both at the same time.

As for the deletion... I don't do activerecord much these days, but I think you're free to do whatever you want with your files. I don't think deleting a duplicate file will do any harm, and if it does.. Well, you use source control, right ? :)

Comment: Yes, I do use version control. Thanks for the info, Ksol!